# How to disable automatic file path update/routing when I move a file in WebStorm?

Tags: autocomplete, webstorm

Whenever I move a *.js file to a different folder, WebStorm automatically parses the file contents and adds `../../../../../` to the included file paths (ie. RequireJS define statements). This has proven to ALWAYS be inaccurate and undesired, I've had enough of trying to fix this mistake every time, so I want to completely turn off this feature.

Any ideas how to turn it off in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it's not possible to turn it off. I can only suggest moving files outside of WebStorm, in system file manager. Please vote for [WEB-9188](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9188)

Related ticket: [WEB-8797](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8797).